# Canvas Emptied but Reappears

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have seen several solutions on this issue but have not found one yet that works for my situation.
I have a chart being made with `chart.js` which uses `canvas` to display. I have a function that is supposed to clear the `canvas` so that I can then redraw the chart with different x variables. The function works initially but as soon as I start to hover on my cleared canvas the old contents reappear. More specifically it seems to reappear if I am hovering over on of the previous data points.

Here is the function:

```
function empty(){
    canvas = document.getElementById("loansChart");
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

**EDIT**

If a canvas contained items that had hover initiated function items, do those items still exist (just invisible) in the canvas?

Comment: This is going to be hard to answer without a stackblitz or something that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: working on trying to get a demonstration. Unfortunately JSFiddle does not have the chart.js plugin

Comment: It does. There are many fiddles with chart.js. I usually use [plkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/?open=lib%2Fscript.js) and a cdnjs-import `<script src=“https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.js“></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the chart.js functions for updating and clearing charts rather than the ones for the html canvas.
The docs are quite straightforward. https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Thank you, I had honestly overlooked this feature. I will likely have followup questions but I will mark this solved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57999206/chart-js-update-to-x-axis-not-updating