# Chart.js Update to X Axis Not Updating

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been trying to get my charts x axis to update without having to refresh the page or clear the canvas. Below is my `js` for the function that updates the values for the labels and then is supposed to update the chart. I have also tried `ctx.update();`

Chart.js V2.8

```
function dateRange(){
    var date1 = document.getElementById('date1').value;
    var date2 = document.getElementById('date2').value;
    date1 = date1.replace(/-/g,"");
    date2 = date2.replace(/-/g,"");
    raw_dates = raw_dates.filter(function(x){
        return x > date1 && x < date2;
    });
    dates = raw_dates;
    ctx.data.labels.update();
}
```

**EDIT** `dates` is my array that stores the values for `data.labels` and `ctx` is my chart.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to disable chart animation, and instance the chart and canvas inside a variable and then try to destroy chart and make undefined the canvas (to free memory), aftwerwards create a new chart.

Comment: In past attempts to clear the canvas or initialize a blank one, there has been issues with the old chart re-appearing after I hover over a position that carries an old data point from the chart.

Comment: here is a link with my initial issues attempting to do this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962123/canvas-emptied-but-reappears

Comment: chart and canvas in a global var scope?

Answer (score 0):

```
var chart_holder, canvas_holder = null;

function drawChart(){
    try{
      chart_holder.destroy()
      canvas_holder = undefined;
    }catch(e){}

    canvas_holder = document.createElement("canvas");
    $('#divelement').empty().append(canvas_holder);

    chart_holder = new Chart(canvas_holder, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {...}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to instance the chart in a variable and update the variable. You can see it in my [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xupuzizita/1/edit?html,js,output).

You can find more information about [updating charts in the docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html).

Important part:

```
let chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), { // can be any variable name
  type: 'line',
  data: data,  
  options: options
});

function addDataButton(){
  addData()
  chart.update() // chartInstance.update()
}
```